# use FindNext in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a very basic application in MS Access to check some data.
I have a Texbox and a button in a Form.
My simple goal: I just want to write something in the test box, click the button and retrieve the first record that matches that search. So I can check all the fields. Then I click again and get next record, etc.
If I write this some basic code in On Click button event

```
DoCmd.FindRecord "XXX", , True, , True
```

It works and first record with XXX is found.

However, when I replace the fixed "XXX" and use the text from the Texbox (called ProjectBox) it doesn't work
For example

```
DoCmd.FindRecord ProjectBox.Value, , True, , True  
DoCmd.FindRecord ProjectBox.Text, , True, , True
```

Both the statements fail... Can you suggest something?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the row of code, invoke the event, and in the Immediate pane type, `?ProjectBox.Value = "XXX"` or whatever the value `XXX` actually is, what happens?

Comment: For some reason if I put a breakpoint this immediate pane does not appear.. I use an Access 365 db... I could add a pane called "Watches" where I can see some expressions and it confirms my value.

Comment: In the watch pane I see: Watch :   : ProjectBox.Value : "XXX" : Variant/String : Form_etc etc.

Comment: If you press `CTRL+G` you should get to the Immediate pane.

Comment: Yes, now I see  the immediate pane. However, if I put this statement MsgBox "Go to " & ProjectBox.Value   I can see the correct value that is H76 in my case. But in the immediate pane I have: ?ProjectBox.Value = "H76"
False

Comment: and in the watches pane I have (as said before)  Watch :   : ProjectBox.Value : "H76" : Variant/String : Form_InputForm2.Command36_Click

Comment: What about `?Trim(ProjectBox.Value) = "H76"`?

Comment: I was wrong! I re-run and I have ?Trim(ProjectBox.Value) = "H76"
True

?ProjectBox.Value = "H76"
True

Comment: I had misplaced the breakpoint... I just want to confirm that I have the following: ?Trim(ProjectBox.Value) = "H76"
True

?ProjectBox.Value = "H76" 
True

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229411/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-fff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write code to search + check the data records, but why not just drop a text box on a existing form. You enter some search like your XXX and then place a button beside that text box.

So, say you have this:

[image]

So I dropped on a text box (txtSearch) and a button.

So, now the code when I click on the button can be this:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()

  Me.Filter = "HotelName like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*'"
  Me.FilterOn = True
  
  
End Sub
```

So now the form is filtered, and you can navagate back and forth though ALL the reocrds that match. I mean, you want to filter some data - but where, when, how do you want to deal with the results? It don't make much sense to say pull some data and JUST filter it in code, since then how do you (or the user) deal with that resulting data?

Of course in any form, a user can hit control-F and this dialog will popup:

[image]

So, this is not somthing you would much often need to write any code for, since it is built in.

Perhaps you wondering how to traverse, seach, process the data but NOT with the UI (user interface) but ONLY say in VBA code?

Well, then you could write this code that takes the input from the text box above and do this:

```
  Dim strSQL        As String
  
  strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels WHERE HotelName LIKE '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*'"
  
  Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
  
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  
  Do While rst.EOF = False
  
     Debug.Print "ID and Hotel name match = " & rst!ID & "," & rst!HotelName
     
     rst.MoveNext
  Loop
  
  rst.Close
```

So the above is pure code - does not use the form. So, if in above I typed in Banff, then the debug.print (ctrl-g - immedate window) would display this output:

```
Output:
ID and Hotel name match = 153,Banff Springs
ID and Hotel name match = 188,Banff Hotelling
ID and Hotel name match = 206,Banff Inn
ID and Hotel name match = 292,Best of Banff
```

[image]

So the issue is NOT writing code to search or filter data, but WHERE, WHEN, HOW you going to present that data to the user.

Since you going to type in some search into a text box, then it makes A WHOLE LOT of sense to build a form, but as noted, forms have that search ability built in, but you can certainly set a filter on a form, and then all of the "actions" of moving next or previous is handled by the simple next/previous abilities built into the form. Thus you write only a wee bit of code to filter - but the form's built in navigation thus saves you from having to write all that next/previous code.

Answer (score 0):

at the end the following code seems to work properly

```
Me!comboProject.SetFocus
DoCmd.FindRecord ProjectBox.Value, acEntire, False, acSearchAll, True, acCurrent, True
```

First I need to focus on the field
then I run DoCmd.FindRecord with acCurrent parameter
For some reason other parameters like acAll etc. do not work

Thank you for all the suggestions I received.